# In a Material-UI single-select <Table>, how does one implement in-row controls?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm implementing an `<IconMenu>` in each row of a single-select table.  `<Table onRowSelection=` provides an event for tracking the current row.  Unfortunately, if the user first selects the row, then clicks on the `<IconMenu>` the row first sees the click on the `<IconMenu>` as a deselect, so there's no selected row when the `<IconMenu><MenuItem onClick=` fires.

I've hacked around some of this (retaining the last-seen selection), but there are still issues; in particular, the row highlight is gone, so the user may be unsure which row they clicked on.

*Is there a clean way to inhibit the row-selection behavior altogether when the `<IconMenu>` in the row is clicked on?*

Do you think I should write up an issue on https://github.com/callemall/material-ui?

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this behavior by stopping the event propagation in each  that contains an `<IconMenu>`. In order to do this just add a  with an onClick handler to each  that contains an `<IconMenu>`. Something like this:

```
<TableRowColumn>
    <div onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}}><IconMenu></div>
</TableRowColumn>
```