# reactjs - make checkbox and row in table behave differently in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I want to make checkbox and row in table work differently. Now, when I click the row, checkbox is also clicked, and the other way work same, too. What I want to do is when I click the row, the dialog pops up, and when I click the checkbox, only checkbox is clicked, not dialog being worked.

Comment: what is your try?

Comment: Is the checkbox inside the row?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: This is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110341/in-a-material-ui-single-select-table-how-does-one-implement-in-row-controls/43506365#43506365

Answer (score 0):

attach the event listener to the each separately.
Can you also share your workaround here.
Will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add a `e.stopPropagation();` in each of the onClick event handler(one for row the other for checkbox) respectively.

In the onClick method paramater, pass in e. Then call the method on the e object.

For example

```
onClick={e => {
         e.stopPropagation();
         // Do whatever you want
        }}
```